# How do I return a limited set of columns in a Castle ActiveRecord query?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, castle-activerecord

and have it map to a strongly typed object?

Suppose I have a entity Blog with Id,Name,Posted,IsUglyFace,YerMom

but I just only want/need Name and Posted columns.  I tried to do something like:

IList blogs = repository.SimpleQuery("select Name, Posted from Blog");

This dumps out a ton more SQL and gives back an error, could not map to given object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/08/26/Partial-Object-Queries-With-NHibernate.aspx

Bonus: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/08/26/Lazy-Property-Loading-In-NHibernate.aspx